# How can I increment the input statement in python?

Tags: python-3.x

my question is how do I get it to show up as "Student 1 name," "Student 2 name" etc as it goes through the loop for all 12 names?

```
students = 12
for x in range(students):
    name = str(input('Student name: '))
    grade = int(input('Enter average grade: '))
```

Comment: `input('Student {} name'.format(x + 1))`

Answer (score 0):

To add to Andrew Li's comment, you can also append string directly in python using the "+" operator:

In case you don't want to use the format method, you can also try this:

```
name = input("Student " + str(x + 1) + " name: ")
```